# Python: Combining two strings and selecting unique elements out of it

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

*I would like to state that I am new to programming and to Python. I did try doing research before posting this question but my lack of knowledge of even basics did not help yielding any results, thus requiring me to ask here.*

I have two strings which are like:

```
 str_a = "100,101,105,304"
 str_b = "400,500,101"
```

I need to combine these strings into one so I use:

```
  str_c = str_a + "," + str_b
```

And my issue starts here. In this new string, where there are elements (numbers) separated by a comma, I want to have each item listed only once. The order of numbers do not matter but if it was ascending, it would be pretty amazing.

What can I do to combine these two, having each number listed once, if possible ordered small to large?

Since these are strings, I am not even sure if I can iterate through?

Your help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can iterate through strings in Python, i.e. `for i in string:`. Just a side note.

Comment: What do you want at the end?  A string?  A list of the unique numbers that you can iterate through? Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
str_a = "100,101,105,304"
str_b = "400,500,101,2000"
l = str_a.split(',') + str_b.split(',')
print ','.join(sorted(set(l), key=int))
```

The output is:

```
100,101,105,304,400,500,2000
```

Thanks Oren for the comment! I've added `key=int` as an extra argument to `sorted` to compare the elements of the list as integers instead of strings. This argument allows one to specify a function of one argument that will be called on each element of the list to extract a comparison key. In our case, we use `int` to convert each element to an integer.

Comment: Notice that the sorting compares the parts as strings (i.e 'a' < 'b' and '1111' < '2'), without evaluating the numbers. In the case of only 3-digits numbers it works fine, but a more generic solution would be: `print ','.join(sorted(set(l), key = int))`

Comment: For a bit more detail, the general approach here is that each string is converted a list, splitting on the comma.  The two are then combined.  `set()` removes the duplicate elements, `sorted()` sorts, and the `join()` combines it all back into a comma separated string

Comment: Thank you Anton for this great simple and elegant solution. And thank you Oren and Ernie for your kind explanations. Really appreciate it ernie for taking your time. Thanks a lot. And Oren, I will check that key thing, it seems very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the strings up using the split method:

```
str_a_vals = str_a.split(",")
str_b_vals = str_b.split(",")
```

Then do:

```
allVals = str_a_vals
allVals += str_b_vals

str_c = ",".join(set(allVals))
```

Comment: why `.extend` ?? wouldn't it be better to just append the list/set with `str_a_vals + str_b_vals`?

Comment: Wasn't familiar with that syntax.

Comment: Thank you crazycasta for your answer and taking your time. Appreciate it!

Comment: @CrazyCasta The `+` operator works the same way for appends in python.  But somehow i think it's personal preference to choose `extend` over `append` or vice versa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend

Comment: @2er0 There is a big difference between `extend` and `append`. The `+` operator does a local extend (`extend` works on the list and doesn't return a value, `+` creates a new object and returns it). The difference between `extend` and `append` is that `extend` adds the elements of the list to the list whereas `append` adds the list itself to the list (ends up w/ [1,2,[3,4]]).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do stuff like sorting and selecting numbers, storing the numbers in strings is  probably not the right approach. Try using lists, like  this:

```
list_a = [100,101,105,304]
list_b = [400,500,101]
```

Getting the unique elements of the combined lists would be as easy as

```
unique = set(list_a + list_b)
```

and getting them in ascending order is

```
ascending = sorted(list_a + list_b)
```